# How to send a DatagramPacket over a NetworkInterface?

Tags: java, windows-7, network-programming, udp, broadcast

I want to send a UDP broadcast message. With Windows XP there are no problem, but [Windows 7 sends broadcast only to one network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615275/udp-broadcast-in-windows-7-does-it-work). How should I do?

Comment: You can attach a DatagramSocket to each IP address of each NetworkInterface.

Comment: Please explain better your answer

Comment: In TCP you can bind a Socket to an interface and I believe you can bind a DatagramSocket to an interface as well, but I haven't tried it.