# Can I receive different domain global UDP broadcast package in Windows?

Tags: network-programming, udp, broadcast

Is it possible get a different domain global UDP broadcast (255.255.255.255) package form the device **which directly connected to PC or connected to the same layer 1 hub with PC?**

For example:

```
PC(Windows 7) network adapter info:
 IP Address : 10.1.146.46
 Sub Mask : 255.255.254.0
 Gateway : 10.1.147.254

Device(Linux) network adapter info:
 IP Address : 192.168.1.1
 Sub Mask : 255.255.255.0
 Gateway : 192.168.1.254
```

**These two devices are directly connected by Ethernet cable
or connected to the same layer 1 Hub.**

When these two devices set as the same domain ip address, they can communicate with global UDP broadcast.

However when I modify the device IP address as above. The device can receive package from PC and response global UDP broadcast package. But I can't catch any package by Wireshark in PC. It's be blocked by Windows?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but what do you mean by "same domain"? Are you talking about same network id? BTW, did you checked Windows' firewall?

Comment: For example, Same domain means the device IP address be set as "10.1.146.252/23" "10.1.147.254". Yes, I already checked firewall.

Comment: OK I call it same network id. There are some related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615275/udp-broadcast-in-windows-7-does-it-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES.

I already got command package from different domain UDP broadcast package.

There is something wrong in sending package on Linux.

Not Windows issue.