# UDP Broadcasting with Indy Sockets: how to select the right Interface?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, indy, c++builder-2006

*Using C++Builder2006*

I'm modifying an old, small program which do these things:

1. send a UDP broadcast message (using the 255.255.255.255 address)
2. get the answer from all the connected devices (hardware stuffs equipped with a RabbitCore RCM3200)
3. Optionally broadcast another UDP message containing the MAC address of one of them and the correct network configuration that that device must set for itself.

(This 'cause the device can have a wrong IP/Netmask when installed and there's a need for a method IP-independent to set it.
This is a well established method from the device producer, so it cannot be changed, i'm just describing what i'm doing).

The problem i'm facing is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615275/udp-broadcast-in-windows-7-does-it-work): in short, Win7 does'nt send the UDP message through all the interfaces, but only through the "preferred" one.
Since the program was built using an Indy UDPClient socket (TIdUDPClient) i'd like to keep it as it is.

**Questions:**

1. There's a way to "force" the UDP socket to send thru a specific Network interface? This way i could "manually" loop and send the broadcast to all the (relevant) networks
2. If not.... what should i do to obtain the same result?

Comment: Perhaps i have'nt been clear, sorry:
" Since the program was built using an Indy UDPClient socket (TIdUDPClient) i'd like to keep it as it is." means that i'd like to find a solution still using the Indy component, not that i want to keep the app sending the broadcast message using just one interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's a way to "force" the UDP socket to send thru a specific Network interface?

`TIdUDPClient` has a `BoundIP` property for that exact purpose.  You will have to call `TIdUDPClient.Binding.CloseSocket()` each time you want to change the `BoundIP`, unless you bind a different `TIdUDPClient` object for each adapter.

> This way i could "manually" loop and send the broadcast to all the (relevant) networks

Depending on the version of Indy you are using, you can use the `TIdStack.LocalAddresses` property, or the `TIdStack.AddLocalAddressesToList()` or `TIdStack.GetLocalAddressList()` method, to get a list of available local IP addresses that you can then loop through.

Comment: Thanks.
But I'm unable to find a way to use TidStack.
that class itself is not instantiable 'cause is abstracy, i can't fin a definition of the Derived TIdStackWindows... i've tried (as i've found it) also the GStack variable but i don't know where it's declare (not in the IdGlobal.hpp, apparently)

Comment: @FabioCalzolari the global `GIdStack` object pointer is declared in the `IdStack.hpp` header. And there is a `BoundIP` property in `TIdUDPClient` in Indy 10. Are you using Indy 9 instead?

Comment: Yes, Indy9 was included in BCB2006.

Comment: `TIdUDPClient` didn't support binding to a specific interface in Indy 9. But you can add it by deriving from `TIdUDPClient` and overriding the virtual `GetBinding()` method.